# How to set UITableView to Grouped?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder, xib

In an iPhone navigation based app, I want to add a second tableview but have its design available in IB.  I've added a new empty XIB and dragged a UITableView onto it.  I want to setup the layout through IB.  I've created a controller for this tableview and set the File's Owner class in IB to this controller.  I linked the tableview to File's Owner as well. I set the tableview to grouped in IB.  However, that does not translate at runtime.  I still have a plain tableview.  In fact, none of the Inspector settings work at runtime.  What have I missed?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure when you instantiate the view controller you do so using `initWithNibName:bundle:` using the name of the file you've created.

Answer (score 1):

```
UITableView *myTableView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,80,320,480) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your tableview and open it's inspector. In the first tab of the inspector, expand the "TableView" and you should see an option called Style. Change it from "Plain" to "Grouped".

If you can't find this, try this on your viewdidload
tableView.style = UITableViewStyleGrouped

Comment: tableView.style is a readonly property, this is not the best way to do it